# Gorilla WebSocket compared with golang.org/x/net/websocket

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

According [Gorilla Websockets Project](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#gorilla-websocket-compared-with-other-packages) it is not possible to send pings and pongs using **golang.org/x/net/websocket**. At the same time, the following is on the project page of [golang.org/x/net/websocket](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket):

> Package websocket implements a client and server for the WebSocket protocol as specified in RFC 6455.

I am a little confused. **golang.org/x/net/websocket** implements RFC 6455 but can not send control frames (cancel, ping, pong) although this is specified in [RFC 6455 - Section Control Frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5)

So what will happen if I use **golang.org/x/net/websocket** package. Will the connection abort after a timeout? In other words, how is it ensured here that the connection does not break off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> According Gorilla Websockets Project it is not possible to send pings and pongs using golang.org/x/net/websocket

The [Gorilla README says](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/a3ec486e6a7a41858210b0fc5d7b5df593b3c4a3#gorilla-websocket-compared-with-other-packages) something different. It says that the golang.org/x/net package cannot *send a ping* or *receive a pong*. It does not say that the package will not send a pong.

The golang.org/x/net package automatically responds to a ping received from the peer by sending a pong to the peer, as does the Gorilla package. Both packages work correctly with a peer that's using ping and pongs to keep the connection alive.

An application that uses the golang.org/x/net/websocket package cannot employ pings and pongs to keep the connection alive. There's no way to send the ping. There's no way to detect that the pong was received.